# How to implement a map<int, list<string> > iterator C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, iterator, operators

It is an exercise from an old exam and i don't know how to solve it.

I have class called dictionary and i want to implement an iterator through the keys that are pair numbers(the_map_key %2 == 0) and i don't know how to implement operator++, and functions begin an end.
Here is the code.

```
class Dictionary{
  private:
     map<int,list<string> > information;
```

that is what the exercise gives me, and the next is what i have done but i don't know how to continue, of course i should do a constructor and a destructor,but this is simple, i have difficulties in the operator++, and functions begin an end.

```
  public:
     class iterator{
       private:
          *d;
       public:
          int & operator *()const;{return *d};
          iterator & operator++(){};
          iterator begin(){};
          iterator end(){};
```

As an example if information contains {1,something},{2,anything},{5,other}{6,an}, iterator information.begin() should point to {2,anything} and iterator++  should point to {6,an}.

Comment: this also seems to be incomplete so hard to give you any pointer in what direction to go

Comment: What does it do? Is it supposed to iterate through every element of every list in the map?

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make sense to me. Your example pairs look like they are of type `<int, string>` but your map pairs are of type `<int, list<string>>`.

Comment: And the example shows the iterator pointing to either `{2, anything}` or `{6, an}` yet `operator*` returns an `int`. This question seems to have a poor definition of `Iterator::value_type`. An iterator range represents a range of typed values, each value has the same type, and this is the return type of `operator*()` (modulo const and/or reference qualifications)

Answer (score 2):

Your iterator class shouldn't contain a pointer, it should contain a `map<int,list<string> >::iterator`. Your `operator*` is trivial - just forward -  but since you apparently want to hide some keys, your `Dictionary::iterator::operator++` can't simply forward to `map<int,list<string> >::iterator`. I don't exactly understand what you want to do with the keys, so I'll leave those details to you.

Comment: i just want to jump the positions in the map which key value are odds

Comment: @FranciscoRuiz: That means your `operator++` has to repeatedly call `operator++` on the underlying `std::map<>::iterator` until the key is odd. However, this is subject to one slight challenge: what exactly is the `end` iterator for your sequence? In particular, if you have an iterator to the last odd key, you must be able to increment that and return `Dictionary::end`. But how does your iterator know that it points to the last odd value? The simplest solution might be to include `std::map<>::end` in your iterator, so your `operator++` knows where to stop.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to solve the problem i wrote the code and i asked to my professor if it was right, he told me it was Ok, so here is the code of what i was trying to do:

```
class Dictionary{
private:
  map<int,list<string> > datos;
public:
  class iterator{
     private:
        map<int,list<string> >::iterator p;
     public:
        int & operator *()const{
            return *p;
        };
        iterator & operator++(){
            while(*p->first %2 != 0 || p != datos.end()){
            p++;
          }
          return p;
        };
        iterator begin(){
            p= datos.begin();
          while(*p->first %2 != 0){
                p++;
            }
            return p;
        };
        iterator end(){
          p= datos.end();
          return p;
        };
  };
}
```

thanks, the answer u gave me helped me to make something more or less well.
If u see any mistake or something i could have done better tell me ty.